# Swift: use switch to turn off button sounds

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a simple counter which fires a sound every time you press a button.
However, my solution to muting the sounds with a switch don't work. Is there any way to mute AVAudioPlayer? Stopping doesn't seem to help, which I guess is normal, because there's no continuous playback of music.
Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

var rowValue: Int = 0

let motivationalQuotes: [String] = ["xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx", ]

@IBOutlet weak var motivationLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func subtractRowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if rowValue > 0 {
        rowValue = rowValue - 1
    } else {
        rowValue = 0
    }

    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"

    playSubtractSound()
    motivateThem()

}

@IBAction func addRowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    rowValue = rowValue + 1
    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"

    playAddSound()
    motivateThem()

}

@IBOutlet weak var rowCount: UILabel!


@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    rowValue = 0
    rowCount.text = "\(rowValue)"
}


@IBOutlet weak var soundSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switchPressed(sender: UISwitch) {

    if soundSwitch.on {
        beepPlayer.volume = 0

    } else {
        beepPlayer.stop()
    }

}

func motivateThem(){
    if(rowValue > 0 && rowValue < 2)
    {
        motivationLabel.text = motivationalQuotes[0]
    }
    else if(rowValue > 19)
    {
        motivationLabel.text = motivationalQuotes[8]
    }
}

let addSoundURL =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("add", withExtension: "aif")!
let subtractSoundURL =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("subtract", withExtension: "aif")!
var beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

func playAddSound(){
    beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: addSoundURL, error: nil)
    beepPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    beepPlayer.play()
}

func playSubtractSound(){
    beepPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: subtractSoundURL, error: nil)
    beepPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    beepPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: How about setting the volume property to 0 to mute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't play the sound if there is no need.

```
if soundSwitch.on { playAddSound() }
```

Comment: You mean inside my func "switchPressed"?

Comment: inside `subtractRowButton` and `addRowButton`